# How to create custom keyboard binding

Tags: gnome, key-mapping

Is there a way to modify keyboard layout in Gnome in a such way that the
following modifications will be available?

```
; --- Backspace
<Alt-;> --- ;
<Alt-h> --- LeftArrow
<Alt-j> --- DownArrow
<Alt-k> --- UpArrow
<Alt-l> --- RightArrow
```

where `---` means one key press would be changed to another in manner like the latter was press on the unchanged keyboard layout.

Comment: I dunno what this has got to do with Gnome? I'm sure `xmodmap` will be very suitable for this job (on console; I'm not so fond of GUI tools in this respect) Although I concede that for new users, this approach might be a little hard to do due to the tool's "cryptic" syntax.

Comment: I find out that it is not true xmodmap cannot support this kind of modifications. xmodmap is pretty trivial key mapping tool without any programmable features. In my case xmodmap changes the behavior of the whole system related to alt key (alt will not be anymore as functional key it was before). If I am not right please provide any clues of the solution.

Comment: @itun This is true, xmodmap cannot achieve what you want. It's simply a map layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too attached to Gnome, KDE has the ability to bind keys to simulate other keys or even dbus commands in fact.

On other DEs you can still bind your keys to `xvkbd` as a way to emulate keys and bind these to your DE "shortcuts" utility. If there is no such utility you can still use `xbindkeys`. Here are 2 short tutorials to set those up :

[xvkbd](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xvkbd_tutorial.html)

[xbindkeys](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xbindkeys_tutorial.html)

You will find that even with these low level tools, some websites like youtube will not work well with an `<Alt-h> --- LeftArrow` keybinding.
I have not found a way to do this at a lower level still. I suspect that it would require a programmable keyboard to achieve what you seek seamlessly. Otherwise it's still very useable and it saves enormous amounts of time, especially if you have such a setup on emacs.